# Jenkins Workflow stage concurrency within same slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Assuming I have a configuration of slaves similar to this one:

```
= Master
|
|_ Slave 1
| |_Executor 1
| |_Executor 2
| |_Executor 3
|
|_ Slave 2
| |_Executor 1
| |_Executor 2
| |_Executor 3
|
|_ Slave 3
  |_Executor 1
  |_Executor 2
  |_Executor 3
```

I would like to parallelise a script so that one of the parallel steps

- cannot be run concurrently on the same slave
- can be run concurrently on other slaves

(I have a resource that is unique per slave, but each slave have this resource).

From what I read on the documentation, it seems like I cannot use stage concurrency as it will be unique on a Jenkins Master level (Wont be executed concurrently on different slaves)

> A concurrency of one is useful to let you lock a singleton resource, such as deployment to a single target server. Only one build will deploy at a given time: the newest which passed all previous stages.

How could I achieve this result?

Comment: there is "Heavy Job Plugin" that works for Freestyle jobs. Don't know if can be used for Pipeline though.